# add depth to an image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an image and I rotated it with CSS to give it a perspective. I'd like to add a thickness to it to make it look like a book, like this:

[image: result expected]

The code/result I have used so far is as follows:

```css
.thumb {
  perspective: 600px;
}

#cover {
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transform: rotateY( 45deg);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -40px 25px 55px 6px #85919d;
  box-shadow: -40px 25px 55px 6px #85919d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb">
  <img id="cover" src="https://about.canva.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/01/children_bookcover.png">
</div>
```

Comment: afaik you can't do this with just css.

Comment: You can probably achieve it with multiple divs/pseudo elements, the thickness part would just be divs that is skewed. I think it's doable but will need some time to come up with it

Comment: [This demo](https://codepen.io/pirrera/pen/tKFhI) looks a bit similar to your intended goal. Found here: http://freefrontend.com/css-image-effects/

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://codepen.io/pirrera/pen/tKFhI

Answer (score 4):

Ok after playing around for awhile I came up with this. I am sure there are other ways of achieving the same thing, in my example I am using borders to create the shadow angles. Tested on FF but it appears we need max-height in chrome

I added box shadow to the image because there was a "crack" with the borders and the box-shadow fills it up

```css
.thumb {
  transform: rotate( -33deg) skew(20deg);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.divider {
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  border-right: 20px solid grey;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
}

.bottom {
  height: 20px;
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 220px;
  border-top: 20px solid grey;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cover {
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 300px;
  box-shadow: -19px 19px 0px 0 grey, -19px 19px 0px 0 grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb">
  <div class="left">

  </div>
  <img id="cover" src="https://about.canva.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/01/children_bookcover.png">
  <div class="divider">

  </div>
  <div class="bottom">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link: https://codepen.io/jackoliver/embed/JKqAYp/?height=600&theme-id=0&default-tab=result&embed-version=2#result-box

```
transform: scale(.8) rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
```

Look for the line that contain that code I think is line 24

It's almost like what you want. Check the scss tag on the codepen snippet it may help. You can view also the compiled css